# Save to pdf from a weird string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

From my XML file, I got a weird string (I think it's a blob data).
It looks like this:

0x244033242D212E430D21E2E3[.......]

It's a very very long string. My DB administrator told me that it comes from the database.
How to convert this string to a valid PDF file?

Thank you very much.

Regards,
Kael

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends the database's manner of storing blob data, but if the format's not too exotic then the [NSData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSPropertyListSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/SerializePlist/SerializePlist.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH7-SW1) classes should be able to convert it into something manageable.

Comment: Hi Elise, thank you for your answer but it's not really help me. I tried with a NSPropertyListSerialization object but I didn't received "something manageable", just the same string.

Comment: That's too bad. One other thought I had but didn't write in my answer: could it possibly be an image?